# ¿Cómo puedo consumir el siguiente servicio SOAP con JAVA usando JAX-WX?

Tags: java, jax-ws

espero que me puedan ayudar porfavor

Tengo el siguiente request en xml que es para consumir un servicio SOAP:

```html
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:wsb="url_de_servicio"
xmlns:v1="http://parametro_soap11">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <wsb:consulta>
            <controlData>
                <v1:messageUUID>?</v1:messageUUID>
                <v1:requestDate>?</v1:requestDate>
                <v1:sendBy>?</v1:sendBy>
                <v1:version>?</v1:version>
            </controlData>
            <consulta>
                <accion>?</accion>
                <iccid>?</iccid>
                <aplicacion>?</aplicacion>
            </consulta>
        </wsb:consulta>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Quisiera saber como se puede consumir utilizando JAX-WS ya que simplifica el código en vez de realizar la petición con métodos puros de JAVA, he intentado el siguiente código:

```js
Service service = new Service();
Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new URL(endPoint));
call.setOperationName("consulta");
Object[] controlData = {parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4};
Object[] consulta = {parm5, parm6, parm7};
Object[] params = {controlData, consulta};
respuesta = (String) call.invoke(params);
```

En este punto no consigo tener una respuesta exitosa del servicio o un response que sea correcto, es decir que en eclipse al realizar el invoke me envía una excepción hasta ahorita no he logrado que funcione, alguien tiene una idea de como consumirlo??